# Recursively list files and directories in an FTP server using Java

Tags: java, ftp, ftp4j

I'm currently using a Java FTP library (ftp4j) to access a FTP server. I want to do a file count and directory count for the server, but this means I would need to list files within directories within directories within directories, etc.

How is this achievable? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Extract from the code:

```
client = new FTPClient();
try {
    client.connect("");
    client.login("", "");
    client.changeDirectory("/");
    FTPFile[] list = client.list();
    int totalDIRS = 0;
    int totalFILES = 0;
    for (FTPFile ftpFile : list) {
        if (ftpFile.getType() == FTPFile.TYPE_DIRECTORY) {
            totalDIRS++;
        }
    }
    message =
        "There are currently " + totalDIRS + " directories within the ROOT directory";
    client.disconnect(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using recursive functions.
This is could be a function that checks a directory for files, then you can do a check if a file has a child, that would be a directory.
If it has a child you can call that same function again for that directory, etc.

Like this pseudo java here:

```
void Function(String directory){
 ... run through files here
 if (file.hasChild())
 {
  Function(file.getString());
 }
}
```

I'm sure you can use that kind of coding in counting the files as well...

Answer (score 0):

Make a recursive function that given a file that might be a directory returns the number of files and directories in it. Use `isDir` and `listFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a recursive function like below.

*Note that my code uses [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/), not ftp4j, what the question is about. But the API is pretty much the same and ftp4j seems to be an abandoned project now anyway.*

```
private static void listFolder(FTPClient ftpClient, String remotePath) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Listing folder " + remotePath);
    FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(remotePath);
    for (FTPFile remoteFile : remoteFiles)
    {
        if (!remoteFile.getName().equals(".") && !remoteFile.getName().equals(".."))
        {
            String remoteFilePath = remotePath + "/" + remoteFile.getName();

            if (remoteFile.isDirectory())
            {
                listFolder(ftpClient, remoteFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Foud remote file " + remoteFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```